# Get screenshot of curses application

Tags: terminal, screenshot, curses

At a remote site I'm running a [curses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) based application at a [virtual console](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/vcs.4.html). If I'm not at the site to check the application I can view whats going on with any of these commands:

```
$ sudo screenshot 1
$ sudo cat /dev/vcs1
```

But the colourisation and borders gets screwed when I use those commands.

So this is roughly **what I want** and **what I get**:

[image: what I want]
[image: what I get]

Can I somehow get the colourisation and borders (and all the rest) correctly displayed to me. I was thinking in the terms of something like this:

```
$ sudo mysuperscreenshot 1
$ sudo cat /dev/vcs1 > out.txt; vim out.txt
$ sudo cat /dev/vcs1 > out.txt; mysuperviewer out.txt
$ sudo myterminalimport /dev/vcs1 > out.png
```

As you might have noticed there is no X on the remote machine so something like `import` or `gnome-screenshot` will not work (at least as far as I understand).

**Is this possible and in that case how?** Is there some argument or application I'm missing?

**If its not possible: why is that?** Is there some conceptual thing I'm missing that make this question flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data that you can read back from the virtual console device omits the video-attributes — only the 8-bit characters that occupy each cell.  There are no system calls which can give you this information (see the [**`console_ioctl`**](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/4-console_ioctl/) manual page).

If you ran your application using **`screen`** (or tmux, etc.), then you could connect to that application and see something comparable on your local machine, with the caveat that neither is likely to do well translating line-drawing if the remote machine is not using a UTF-8 locale.